# Fechar div em um link de saida ou ao clicar fora

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá tenho o seguinte codigo.

```js
function abreConteudo(element) {
    alert($(element).attr('class'));
    alert($(element > "div.descricaoobs").text());
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.botao_melhor_leitura").click(function (e) {
        $(this).find(".descricaoobs").attr('style', 'display:block;');

        var mousex;
        var estado = $(this).find(".descricaoobs").attr('class');
        /*var tipVisX = $(window).width();*/
        $(this).find(".descricaoobs").css({
            right: mousex
        });
    })
})
```

```css
.descricaoobs{
 overflow-y:hidden;
 border:  #999999 solid 1px;
 background-color:#F8F8FF;
 position:center;
 padding:1px 3px;
 position: absolute;
 display: none; 
 text-align: left;
 font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Globo.com Bootstrap</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
    </head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <body>
        <table style="width:100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>obs</td>
                <td>Teste1</td>
                <td>Teste2</td>
                <td>Teste3</td>
                <td>Teste4</td>
                <td>Teste5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='botao_melhor_leitura'>
                        <button type="button">Clique aqui</button>
                        <div class='descricaoobs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis euismod dolor, eu consequat qua</div>
                </td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis euismod dolor, eu consequat quam. Aenean suscipit lectus massa, sit</td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis euismod dolor, eu consequat quam. Aenean suscipit lectus massa, sit</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

que tem por finalidade abrir uma div com um texto quando clico no botao.Até ai tudo bem, o problema e que preciso de um botao para sair dessa div. Pode ser um botao de fechar ou quando clicar fora da div fechar a mesma.

Alguém pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o seguinte código:

```
        $(document).mouseup(function(){
            $('.descricaoobs').hide();
        });
```

Isso vai fazer com que essa div seja escondida ao clicar em qualquer outro lugar do documento.

Veja funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/131gn0uj/1/

Comment: pode usar também $('.descricaoobs').css('visibility','hidden');

Answer (score 0):

Deixo duas sugestões que estão nesta verificação:

```
if (el.hasClass('fechar') || !el.closest('.botao_melhor_leitura').length)
```

A primeira implica usar um `span` por exemplo para ser o botão de fecho. A outra é como pediu, procurando clics fora da "div mãe".

Nota que quando escreves `.attr('style','display:block;');` estás a sobreescrever **todo** o conteúdo desse atributo. Usar `.css('display', 'block');` seria bem mais correto/seguro

```js
function abreConteudo(element) {
    alert($(element).attr('class'));
    alert($(element > "div.descricaoobs").text());
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.botao_melhor_leitura").click(function (e) {
        $(this).find(".descricaoobs").css('display', 'block');

        var mousex;
        var estado = $(this).find(".descricaoobs").attr('class');
        /*var tipVisX = $(window).width();*/
        $(this).find(".descricaoobs").css({
            right: mousex
        });
    })
})

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var el = $(e.target);
    if (el.hasClass('fechar') || !el.closest('.botao_melhor_leitura').length) $('.descricaoobs').hide();

});
```

```css
.descricaoobs {
     overflow-y:hidden;
     border: #999999 solid 1px;
     background-color:#F8F8FF;
     position:center;
     padding:1px 3px;
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     text-align: left;
     font-size:12px;
 }
 .fechar:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>obs</td>
        <td>Teste1</td>
        <td>Teste2</td>
        <td>Teste3</td>
        <td>Teste4</td>
        <td>Teste5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>
            <div class='botao_melhor_leitura'>
                <button type="button">Clique aqui</button>
                <div class='descricaoobs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis euismod dolor, eu consequat qua. <span class="fechar"> (fechar)</span>

                </div>
        </td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis euismod dolor, eu consequat quam. Aenean suscipit lectus massa, sit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis euismod dolor, eu consequat quam. Aenean suscipit lectus massa, sit</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ydu6hm7L/**

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa maneira de se criar a funcionalidade de "fechar ao clicar fora" é a seguinte:

HTML:

```
 <div id="conteudo" >
  <a href="#">Meu link</a>
    <p>Se clicar aqui, não vai poder fechar</p>
</div>

<a id="abre-conteudo" href="#">Aqui abre o #conteúdo. Se clicar aqui, não pode fechar</a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

    $(document).click(function(e)
    {
        var condition = 
             $(e.target).is('#conteudo')  // verifica se o elemento clicado é o #conteudo
             || $('#conteudo').has(e.target).size() // verifica se o elemento clicado está dentro de #conteudo
             || $(e.target).is('#abre-conteudo'); // verifica se o elemento é o clicado é o #abre-conteudo


        if ( condition ) {
           return false;
        }

        $("#conteudo").fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Veja esse [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rv29hm0x/)